# Oracle String Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help in converting the following string into a required format. I will have several values as below. Is there a easy way to do this using REGEXP or something better?

**Current format coming from column A**

```
Region[Envionment Lead|||OTC|||06340|||List Program|||TX|||Z3452|||Souther Region 05|||M7894|||California Divison|||Beginning]

Region[Coding Analyst|||BA|||04561|||Water Bridge|||CA|||M8459|||West Region 09|||K04956|||East Division|||Supreme]
```

**Required Format of column A**

```
Region[actingname=Envionment Lead,commonid=OTC,insturmentid=06340,commonname=List Program]

Region[actingname=Coding Analyst,commonid=BA,insturmentid=04561,commonname=Water Bridge]
```

**revised data**

```
**Column data**  
Region[Coding Analyst|||BA|||reg pro|||04561|||08/16/2011|||Board member|||AZ|||06340|||Whiter Bridge|||CA|||M0673|||West Region 09|||K04956|||East Division|||Supreme]

**required Data** 
{actingname=06340, actingid=M0673, insturmentid=BA, insturmentname=Coding Analyst, commonname=West Region 09, stdate=08/16/2011, linnumber=04561, linstate=CA, linname=Supreme}
```

The issue is getting the 10,11,12 and 15 position of the string. I can get anything below 10th position, but not 10 or more string position. Can you please guide me what i'm i missing here

```
'{actingname=\8,actingid=\11,insturmentid=\2,insturmentname=\1,commonname=\12, stdate=\5,linnumber=4,linstate=10,linname=15}'--Here 10,11,12 and 15 posistion are not being fethched
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used REGEXP_REPLACE

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    'Region[Envionment Lead|||OTC|||06340|||List Program|||TX|||Z3452|||Souther Region 05|||M7894|||California Divison|||Beginning]',
    '^Region\[([[:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|([[:digit:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]]*).*',
    'Region[actingname=\1,commonid=\2,instrumentid=\3,commonname=\4]') as replaced
FROM dual
```

or like an update it would be

```
UPDATE table1 
SET col1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(
             col1,
             '^Region\[([[:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|([[:digit:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]]*).*',
             'Region[actingname=\1,commonid=\2,instrumentid=\3,commonname=\4]')
```

Comment: Can’t you solve that based on what I have done so far? You need to add more groups (the pattern inside `()`)  and rearrange where they should go, \1, \2 etc

Comment: It appears that replacing/fetching the 10th + position of the string is not working based on the above solution. I can get anything below 10th position, but not 10 or more string position. Can you please let me know if i'm missing anything here.. on how to fetch 10th position. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson I have revised my sample data for your kind reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr` and `listagg` consecutively

```
with t1(str1) as
(
 select 'Region[Coding Analyst|||BA|||04561|||Water Bridge]' from dual   
),   t2(str2) as
(
 select 'actingname,commonid,insturmentid,commonname' from dual   
),   t3 as
(
select regexp_substr(str1, '[^|||]+', 1, level) str1,
       regexp_substr(str2, '[^,]+', 1, level)||'=' str2,
       level as lvl
  from t1
  cross join t2 
connect by level <= regexp_count(str1, '[^|||]+')
),   t4 as
(
select case when lvl = 1 then 
                 replace(str1,'[','['||str2)
       else
                 str2||str1
       end as str, lvl
  from t3
)    
select listagg(str,',') within group (order by lvl) as "Result String" from t4;

Result String
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Region[actingname=Coding Analyst,commonid=BA,insturmentid=04561,commonname=Water Bridge]
```

*P.S. I considered the second one as a sample, and took the 4 first string due to number of substrings seperated by triple-pipes due to the number of tuple labels ending with equality sign is 4.*
<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/HAV34827)</kbd>

Comment: thank you. I actually need to dynamically select first 4 strings from the actual column and then probably apply your logic. Is there a easy way to extract first 4 from the original string (current format)?

Comment: @stackuser you're welcome. It seems you'd better to hold those information, which should be matched, with common index through table(s).

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select substr(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace
(regexp_replace(regexp_replace("col1",'\[','[actingname='),
                     '\|\|\|',',commonid=',1,1,'i'),
'\|\|\|',',insturmentid=',1,1,'i'),
'\|\|\|',',commonname=',1,1,'i'),
    '\|',']',1,1,'i'),
             1,regexp_instr(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace
(regexp_replace(regexp_replace("col1",'\[','[actingname='),
                     '\|\|\|',',commonid=',1,1,'i'),
'\|\|\|',',insturmentid=',1,1,'i'),
'\|\|\|',',commonname=',1,1,'i'),
    '\|',']',1,1,'i'),'\]')-1            )||']'
from Table1;
```

check:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ddfa0/11

thanks!!!!!!